# ArrayList "cannot be resolved" when trying to access an ArrayList in a method, Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I've created two classes (Team and MarchMadness) to create a MarchMadness bracket in Java. In the `MarchMadness` class, I've created an `ArrayList` of type `Team` for each round and added all the teams for round1. However, I keep getting a "cannot be resolved" error when trying to pull the ArrayList's size and elements in the `randomize` method.

I've tried moving the ArrayList's outside of the `main` method, but then I get an error when trying to add teams to the ArrayList. I've also searched online, but haven't found anything.

Here is my code with only the teams for round1 East.

```
public class Team extends MarchMadness {

    private String name;
    private double rating;
    private int seed;

    public Team(String name, double rating, int seed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.seed = seed;
    }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MarchMadness {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Team> round1East = new ArrayList<Team>();

        round1East.add(new Team("Duke", 0.670, 1));
        round1East.add(new Team("North Dakota St", 0.495, 16));
        round1East.add(new Team("VCU", 0.609, 8));
        round1East.add(new Team("UCF", 0.606, 9));
        round1East.add(new Team("Mississippi St", 0.609, 5));
        round1East.add(new Team("Liberty", 0.549, 12));
        round1East.add(new Team("Virginia Tech", 0.605, 4));
        round1East.add(new Team("Saint Louis", 0.547, 13));
        round1East.add(new Team("Maryland", 0.602, 6));
        round1East.add(new Team("Belmont", 0.579, 11));
        round1East.add(new Team("LSU", 0.626, 3));
        round1East.add(new Team("Yale", 0.572, 14));
        round1East.add(new Team("Louisville", 0.594, 7));
        round1East.add(new Team("Minnesota", 0.578, 10));
        round1East.add(new Team("Michigan St", 0.641, 2));
        round1East.add(new Team("Bradley", 0.504, 15));

    }

    private void randomize() {
        if(round2East.isEmpty()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < round1East.size(); i += 2) {
                int x = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
                if(x == 0) {
                    round2East.add(round1East.get(i));
                } else {
                    round2East.add(round1East.get(i++));
                }
            }
     }

}
```

Comment: This error happens on compilation time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you put the ArrayList outside of the main method, you declare it as an "instance variable". Since the main method is static, you cannot reference a "non-static (instance)" variable in a static method.

The fix would be to just declare it outside of the main method, but make the variable static as well.

```
static ArrayList<Team> round1East = new ArrayList<Team>();
```

Comment: No worries! Here is a nice article about static vs non-static https://medium.com/@gabriellamedas/differences-between-static-and-non-static-methods-in-java-b93156be75c6

Answer (score 0):

You must also try using List  Obj = new ArrayList this allows you to switch between different implementations of the List interface with ease. Polymorphism